# Matrix equation.

Tags: matrices

Let $A=a_{ij}$ be a a square matrix of order $n$ where  $a_{ij}$ belongs to R and satisfies $A^5=16A$. Find $trace$ of $A$.

NOTE:- $Trace$ of $A$ means $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}.$

ATTEMPT:- $A^5=16A$

$\qquad$     $\qquad$       $A^{-1}A^5=16A^{-1}A$  $\qquad$(assuming A to be invertible)

$\qquad$     $\qquad$       $A^4=16I$

I found the matrix as:

$\qquad$   $\qquad$   $ {
        \begin{matrix}
        2 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
}$ $\qquad=2I$ $\qquad$as if $A=2I$ $\implies$ $A^4=(2I)^4=16I$

But here I have assumed that $A$ is invertible.

So i would like to have a more mathematical approach.

Comment: You are not entitled to assume that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not have enough information to compute $\def\tr{\mathrm{tr}\,}\tr A$, as the properties do not determine $\tr A$ uniquely. For example, the following matrices are all solutions to $A^5 = 16A$, but have different traces:
$$ A_1 = 0, \quad \tr A_1 = 0$$
$$ A_2 = 2I, \quad \tr A_2 = 2n $$
$$ A_3 = -2I, \quad \tr A_3 = -2n $$

Comment: Since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, we can at least narrow down the possibilities for the trace to a finite list. Each eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^5=16\lambda$ and hence $\lambda\in\{0,\pm 2,\pm 2i\}$, and the fact that the entries are real force the nonreal eigenvalues to come in conjugate pairs. This leads quickly to the conclusion that the possible traces of such a matrix $A$ are $\{-2n,-2n+2,\ldots,2n-2,2n\}$. One can realize each of these possibilities with variations of martini's examples, namely as direct sums of the zero, identity, and negative identity matrices.

Comment: @yasir, if mine is the sort of answer you're looking for, let me know, and I'll write this up as a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ has $n^2$ elements $a_{ij}$ and whatever complicated be the expression of $A^n$ it has always $n^2$ elements $N_{rs}$ each of them is formulated in function of the other elements $a_{ij}$.

Your matrix equation therefore gives the $n$ numerical equations $N_{ii}=16a_{ii}$;  $i=1,2,...,n$ which is a system of n equations with $n^2$ unknowns.

Thus, in general there are infinitely many real solutions $a_{ij}$. For rational solutions it could be just a finite number of them if the exponent is greater than $3$ but this is another (difficult) story.

Note correction.- There are in fact $n^2$ equations because $N_{ij}=16a_{ij}$. However each of these equations is of degree $n$ and the problem of determination of the $a_{ij}$ becomes hard . Despite of we need only $a_{11}+a_{22}+…..+a_{nn}$, unfortunately the diagonal terms of $N_{rs}$ are function of terms $a_{ij}$ with $i\ne j$.

Comment: It's true that there are infinitely many possibilities for $A$ satisfying the given equation, but there are only finitely many possibilities for its trace.

Comment: Equality of matrices is given iff each of their terms are equal.

Comment: @Travis: Do you mean that 16($a_{11}+....+a_{nn})$=$N_{11}+....+N_{nn}$ have just a finite number of possibilities? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean that the equation $A^5 = 16 A$ leaves only five possibilities for each of the eigenvalues of $A$. On the other hand, the trace of $A$ is the sum of its eigenvalues, so there are only finitely many possibilities for the trace of $A$. For more details, see my comment on martini's answer.

Comment: @Travis: interesting way. I didn't consider eigenvalues. I think you do give an answer clarifying all of this.